# Singular values: for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, expression of $\sigma\left(A+A^\top \right)$ in terms of $\sigma(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, singular-values

For a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ let its singular values be $\sigma_+(A) > 0$ and $\sigma_-(A)\geq 0$.

What is the expression for singular values of $M = A +A^\top$,
i.e., what are $\sigma_+(M)$ and $\sigma_-(M)$ as functions of $\sigma_+(A)$ and $\sigma_-(A)$?

---

---

Is this a hard problem? Initially I though this should be simple, but I struggle to find the expression.

---

---

**Edited later 1:** I'm actually now not sure that $\sigma_+(M)$ and $\sigma_-(M)$  only depend on $\sigma_+(A), \sigma_-(A)$, they might depend on elements of $A$.

**Edited later 2:** Following the discussion to the answer given by `user1551`, I think the answer might change if one instead considers *signed* singular values (which is the definition used in geometric processing. So if you, say, have triangular mesh, then you want to not only measure how much a transformation stretches the space (unsigned, the usual, singular values) but also track if it does flipping of a surface, i.e.,  changing its orientation (signed singular values)).

Comment: Did you try comparing the roots of $\lambda\mapsto\det(\lambda I-AA^{\intercal})$ to those of $\lambda\mapsto\det(\lambda I-(A+A^{\intercal})^{2})$? Both are quadratic polynomials, so it should be easy enough to obtain expressions for the roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot express the singular values of $A+A^T$ in terms of the singular values of $A$. Consider
$$
A(t)=e^{tK}=\underbrace{(e^{tK})(I)(I)}_{\text{SVD}} \text{ where } K=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}.
$$
The singular values of $A(t)$ are all equal to $1$, but the singular values of $A(0)+A(0)^T=2I$ are all equal to $2$ but the singular values of $A(\frac{\pi}{2})+A(\frac{\pi}{2})^T=K+K^T=0$ are zeroes.

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question. But I think it might be the case, that if I use *signed* singular values (for example, this is used in geometric processing) then perhaps it is possible. ? To get signed singular values I need to fix orientation and then sign would imply that matrix flips the orientation.  With signed singular values the two matrices in your example are different.

Comment: if $A= U\Sigma V^\top$ is your SVD, then you require $\det(U)>0$ and $\det(V)>0$ and keep the signs in $\Sigma$. (Your keep the information if there is orientation  flip).

Comment: @them But this is not well defined. E.g. if $A=diag(a,b)$. Then $IAI$ and $I(-A)(-I)$ are both SVD of $A$ where the $U$ and $V$ have determinants $1$. Then are the signed singular values of $A$ $\{a,b\}$ or $\{-a,-b\}$?

Comment: this is defined up to a choice of orientation, so some singular values have positive orientation and some negative orientation. This a standard definition within geometric processing. (Then, regarding signed singular values of $M=A+A^\top$, the same choice of orientation is kept for singular values of $M$)

Comment: Your post answers my original question. But no, in your example the signed singular values of $A$ are different than for $B$. So I still wonder about the signed case. In $A$ two of the signed singular values are positive (for fixed orientation)  and two are negative. While in $B$ all are positive (for the same fixed orientation). The sign shows you the orientation of singular value. As I said you keep the sign up to orientation (in the sense that you can flip all signs of the singular values, this will keep the distinction between positivly and negatively oriented singular values)